# "3-in-1" kits for maytag refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

Would a "3-in-1" kit (SUPCO seems common) help, or should I be budgeting for a replacement refrigerator?

Maytag PTB1953GRW takes several attempts to start the compressor - 10sec buzz; 2min pause; 10sec buzz; 2min pause; ... up to four times until it starts - which it has so far. Condenser coils were not particularly dirty, but I cleaned them anyway to no effect; condenser fan runs fine and can be heard running while the startups are attempted.

**Edit:**

I did install one of the SUPCO units and the refrigerator seems to start reliably now. Time only will really tell. It may be running short of charge, though - I see corrosion around the brazed joints of the tubing - so I'm setting my pennies aside.

Many thanks for the support and comments.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Might the controller be trying to restart the compressor too soon, before any previous pressure had bled away?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. The time from the last compressor cycle is a fairly long time, though I haven't been home enough to actually get the specific start/stop/restart/retry times.

Comment: A new refrigerator may pay for itself in energy cost savings. You can calculate at this web site: [Refrigerator Retirement Savings Calculator](https://www.energystar.gov/index.cfm?fuseaction=refrig.calculator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I serviced air-conditioning units as a service tech for a larger HVAC company in my past life, I always recommended "hard start kits" on every unit. I always installed them on every A/C unit, central or window unit, I or any one in my family ever owned. For the central units, I made my own and for the window units I bought the "SUPCO" type units. They worked very well especially on very hot days when the voltage would drop or when we used to get "brown outs". They work great in cases like yours. I put one on my central unit when it was new and it still works today at 20 years old. If I were you, I would install one so you can get a little more time on the frig you have and may buy some time to budget for when that unit quits. MY 2 CENTS

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the frig is nearing the end of its usable life.  You can try the hard start kit. A new capacitor may be in order as well.  I these don't help I would start saving.

Comment: Many thanks; I did put in one of the hard start kits, but now I'm saving. I'm torn between your reply as answer and d.george's. Both useful and welcome